# Unable to use environment variable for crontab in docker

Tags: environment-variables, cron, dockerfile

I need to add environment variable to a crontab task in a Dockerfile. This is so i can pass the value as a runtime value which Docker can pick up.

But when i start a container from the image and pass environment variables, it is not picked up in the container.

How do i fix it.

Example below:

```
RUN yum install -y cronie
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

ADD dist/*.whl /opt/
RUN pip install /opt/*.whl

WORKDIR /opt/setup
VOLUME /var/docker-share

# Add task to crontab
RUN echo '0 * * * * run.sh --var1 $VAR1 --var2 $VAR2' | crontab -

# Run the command on container startup
CMD crond && while true; do sleep 3600; done
```